# Protect iMaros iim Script

Tags: imacros

is it possible to protect my .iim iMacros script because want to share to somebody?
in block of my script contained:

- URL GOTO
- PROMPT
- Read .csv file
- !EXTRACT
- and using some of !VAR

Please give me guidance or refference. Thank you

Comment: [Here](http://wiki.imacros.net/FAQ#Q:_How_can_I_prevent_my_Player-only_users_from_editing_macros.3F) is a reference to a relevant question in the wiki FAQ.

Comment: i cannot understand to apply that tutorial.. actually not oly password protection i need... can you give me a sample for iMacros protection? btw, .iim file want to share to people where they can set the number begining of !LOOP.. yep, sometimes they need to SET the !LOOP mmaybe starting from .csv 12 or starting from .csv file row 35 etc. how to protect the file? or encryp .iim file become user cannot read part of the line as ussual iMacros syntag...

Comment: Google knows better than I do, because never protect my macros. Moreover I don't advise anybody to play the 'iMacros' macro/script which one can't see the code of. IMHO that's very insecure!

Answer (score 2):

A way to protect your iMacros would be to convert them into Javascript, obfuscate them and share the obfuscated Javascript/iMacros.
The user wont be able to edit and read the source of the script however the sidebar is showing the source code while playing the script. It might sounds difficult but it's very easy because there are programms/tools out there who do the conversion and obfuscation. This is the best protection you can have for an iMacros.

For a full tutorial on how to do it I would suggest you read [this post.](https://xs-sol.com/best-imacros-workarounds-hacks-tipps-tricks/)